# Multiply Double with BigDecimal

Tags: scala, math

I have a BigDecimals that's always have 30 digits after the decimal points.

And I want to multiply them with Double and get a BigDecimal with 30 digits after decimal point.

For exemple I have:

```
    val double = 4.0
    val bd = 0.111111111111111111111111111111

    
    def multiply(d : Double, bd : BigDecimal, scale: Int) = {
    
     BigDecimal.valueOf(d).setScale(scale).*(bd)

    }

// multiply(double,bd,30) => 0.4444444444444444000000000000000000
```

I expected to get `0.444444444444444444444444444444` (30 times 4 after the point)

What is wrong with my method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `bd` isn't a `BigDecimal`, it's a `Double`:

```
scala> val bd = 0.111111111111111111111111111111
val bd: Double = 0.1111111111111111
```

It gets implicitly converted to a `BigDecimal` (after losing precision from `Double`) when you call `multiply`.

To create the `BigDecimal`, you seek, it's probably best to parse a string representation:

```
val bd = BigDecimal("0.111111111111111111111111111111")
// bd.scale is 30
```

It's also probably a good idea to explicitly set the scale again in `multiply` after the multiplication, as it's possible for multiplying two numbers, even with the same scale, to have greater scale than either number.

```
def multiply(d: Double, bd: BigDecimal, scale:Int): BigDecimal =
  (BigDecimal.valueOf(d).setScale(scale) * bd).setScale(scale)
```

Answer (score 3):

Scala's BigDecimal is similar to [Java's BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

- When you multiply two BigDecimals together (using the `*` method on the left one), you get a new BigDecimal whose scale is the sum of the scale of its operands (inputs).
- The variable `bd` is not a BigDecimal, so its name is misleading. It is actually a double. In order to instantiate a BigDecimal, you should use a constructor, for example: `BigDecimal("0.111111111111111111111111111111")`.

```
val bd = BigDecimal("0.111111111111111111111111111111")
val double = 4.0

// There is no need to call `setScale` on `d` due to the first point noted above. Set it after multiplying:
def multiply(d : Double, bd : BigDecimal, scale: Int) =   
  (BigDecimal.valueOf(d) * bd).setScale(scale)

val result = multiply(double, bd, 30)
println(result)
println(result.scale)
```

Result:

```
0.444444444444444444444444444444
30
```